# reactjs unable to pass down this.props into react-chartist

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chartist.js

I would like to pass this.state from "main.js" (parent component) into "bar.js" (child component).

```
//main.js

    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import BarChart from './Bar-chart';

    class Hero extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      labels: ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5/P6'],
      series: [[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 ]]
    }
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="container">
          <div className="row">
              <BarChart data={this.props.labels, this.props.series}/>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default Hero;
```

Here is my child component:

```
//bar.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';
import ChartistGraph from 'react-chartist';
import Legend from 'chartist-plugin-legend';

class BarGraph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

  }

  render() {
    const option = {
      height: '350px',
      plugins: [
        Legend({
          legendNames: ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5/P6'],
        })
      ]
    };

    return (
        <ChartistGraph
          data={this.props.labels, this.props.series}
          options={option}
          type={'Bar'} />
    );
  }

  barData() {
    return ({
        labels: ['P1', 'P2', 'P3', 'P4', 'P5/P6'],
        series: [[ 8, 28, 40, 25, 9 ]]
    });
  };
}

export default BarGraph;
```

In addition, I am still a bit confused between when I should use this.state vs this.props. In this scenario, am I approaching it correctly using this.props?

Comment: If values of labels, series of the component changes in runtime based on user interaction, or some other external condition then its better to use state because then setting the new values to the state would auto render your component.   In case if the values of labels, series of the component is constant and never changes after its initial render then its better to use only props.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your props are not structured as you expect based on how you passed them down.

Try changing the structure of your props to look like this:

```
<BarChart data={{ labels: this.props.labels, series: this.props.series}}/>
```

essentially what this is doing is passing down an object with the keys of labels, and series to your child component. The outer braces mean that everything inside of them will evaluated as JavaScript. So we put more braces to indicate we're passing down an object.

Now on your nested component you should have access to the following structure for this.props:

```
this.props = {
   series: [],
   labels: []
}
```

However, because your parent state is structured exactly as you need for this chartist graph (with a labels array and a series array), if you want to pass down the data object for chartist directly just do this:

```
<BarChart data={this.state} />
```

and you can render your graph like so:

```
        <ChartistGraph
          data={this.props}
          options={option}
          type={'Bar'} />
```

Comment: Please let me know if this answers your main question